# Haskell Let/In in main function

Tags: haskell

My code:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO()
main = do
inFile <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode
content <- hGetContents inFile
let
    someValue = someFunction(content)
    in
    print(anotherFunction(someValue))
    print(anotherFunction2(someValue))
hClose inFile
```

My error:

```
- Type error in application
*** Expression     : print (anotherFunction2(someValue))
*** Term           : print
*** Type           : e -> IO ()
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

I need to print two or more lines with functions that require "someValue".
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use let binding in a do block, don't use the `in` keyword.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    inFile <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents inFile
    let someValue = someFunction(content)
    print(anotherFunction(someValue))
    print(anotherFunction2(someValue))
    hClose inFile
```

Answer (score 8):

The cause of that error message is that when you write

```
let
    someValue = someFunction(content)
    in
    print(anotherFunction(someValue))
    print(anotherFunction2(someValue))
```

the two `print` statements are actually parsed as one:

```
print (anotherFunction (someValue)) print (anotherFunction2 (someValue))
```

In other words, it thinks the second `print` as well as `(anotherFunction2 (someValue))` are also arguments to the first `print`. This is why it complains that `e -> IO ()` (the actual type of `print`) does not match `a -> b -> c -> d` (a function taking three arguments).

You can fix this by adding a `do` after the `in` to make it parse the two statements as separate:

```
let
    someValue = someFunction(content)
    in do
    print(anotherFunction(someValue))
    print(anotherFunction2(someValue))
```

Though, it's better to use the `do`-notation form of `let` here, without any `in`:

```
import System.IO

main :: IO()
main = do
    inFile <- openFile "file.txt" ReadMode
    content <- hGetContents inFile
    let someValue = someFunction content
    print (anotherFunction someValue)
    print (anotherFunction2 someValue)
    hClose inFile
```

I also got rid of some redundant parentheses in the above code. Remember, they are only used for grouping, not for function application in Haskell.